# Convert Bitmap to Image

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, bitmapimage

So after I pull an image out of DLL and put it into an image control it is a BitmapImage. To package it back into the dll it has to be converted back to an image. How can I convert it back to image and how can i repackage it back into the dll? This is all in wpf written in c#.

```
private void compileDLL_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sourcePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\PCAngelResources.dll";
        //destination path
        string dllname = textBox1.Text + "_PCAngelResources.dll";
        string targetPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, dllname);
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, destFile, true);

        //lstImages = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
        //string filename = "PCAngelResources.dll";
        Assembly pcangdll = Assembly.LoadFile(sourcePath);
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("PCAngelResources.DynResources", pcangdll);
        rs = rm.GetResourceSet(culture, true, true);
        ResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter(destFile);

        foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in rs)
        {
            resources.Add((string)resource.Key);
            if (resource.Key.Equals("Branding") || resource.Key.Equals("Advertising"))
            {
                if (resource.Key.Equals("Branding"))
                {
                    writer.AddResource("Branding", image5.Source);
                    //System.Object obj = rm.GetObject((string)resource.Key);
                    //lstImages.Add((string)resource.Key, (Bitmap)obj);
                }
                else
                    if (resource.Key.Equals("Advertising"))
                    {
                        writer.AddResource("Advertising", image6.Source);
                    }
            }
        }
        writer.Generate();
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Done", "Process Finished", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Asterisk, MessageBoxResult.OK);
    }
```

When I do writer.Generate() to make the new dll I get the following error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode' in Assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: Please define the problem more clearly.

Comment: updated code, any new ideas on how to replace existing image with the image user chooses? And any idea how to fix the generate() error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "repackage it back into the DLL" but there is an easy way to convert a WPF image from a BitmapSource back into a System.Drawing.Image. The following method accomplishes that:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a WPF bitmap to a System.Drawing.Bitmap
/// </summary>
/// <param name="wpfBitmap">BitmapSource to convert</param>
/// <returns>A GDI Bitmap</returns>
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap GdiBitmapFromWpfBitmap(BitmapSource wpfBitmap)
{
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wpfBitmap));
    MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
    encoder.Save(imageStream);
    System.Drawing.Bitmap gdiBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imageStream);

    imageStream.Close();
    imageStream.Dispose();

    return gdiBitmap;
}
```