# Issue in converting stream to an array

Tags: c#

```
for (myBitmap.col = 0; myBitmap.col < myBitmap.Height; myBitmap.col++)            
{
    for (myBitmap.row = 0; myBitmap.row < myBitmap.Height; myBitmap.row++)                
    {
        myBitmap.data[myBitmap.row * (int)myBitmap.ScanLineWidth + myBitmap.col + myBitmap.offset] += 5;
    }
}

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(myBitmap.data);

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

//pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(returnimage);

MessageBox.Show("The image brightness conversion is successful");
```

I am facing problem converting memory stream object to an image . error comes of invalid parameter

Comment: It might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196258/convert-bitmap-to-image

Comment: What is myBitmap.data?? Is it byte array??

Answer (score 1):

Try reseting stream pointer before you create image:

```
ms.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
```

Comment: no it is still not working :( is there any other way of converting. i am still receiving an error: parameter is not valid